# Why do Microsoft websites default to Polish on my work network?

Tags: localization, microsoft, msdn

I originally asked this on [Super User](http://superuser.com), but it was ruled off-topic there and referred to here.

I'm in Belgium. When I open MSN, no matter what browser or what machine I use, it's opened using `pl-PL` localization. It doesn't matter whether I open it on my older laptop that's always been at the office, on my desktop that's been imported from the previous dev who worked in Kiev or on my personal Android phone, whether I use Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer. Even my coworkers have this problem.

However, as far as I can tell, it's only Microsoft-related websites that do this. Netflix says I'm in Belgium. Google says I'm in Belgium. Whoismyisp says I'm in London. Whatismyip says I'm in Brussels. Whatismyipaddress says I'm in London. Being in London is understandable since that's where our ISP is located (Colt), but I don't understand why every Microsoft website gives me the Polish site by default, as well as all my coworkers. We think it might have something to do with a network setting, but we're not sure.

What might cause this?

Comment: Crappy localization code on Microsoft's side would seem to be the obvious culprit. You should report it to them.